# How to enable SMTP with Authentication in Bugzilla 4

Tags: 11.04, gmail, smtp, bugzilla

I have installed bugzilla 4.0. It's working, however, I am not able to use the feature to send with SMTP with uthentication.

According to the [release notes](http://www.bugzilla.org/releases/4.0/release-notes.html#v40_feat), if you install: Authen::SASL the SMTP::TLS should be available in the mail drop down.

running ./checksetup --check-modules:

```
Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.52 
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.47 
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.21)     ok: found v2.23 
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     ok: found v0.70 
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.71)     ok: found v1.38 
Checking for                  DBI (v1.41)     ok: found v1.609 
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     ok: found v2.22 
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.00)     ok: found v2.198 
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.910 
Checking for                  URI (any)       ok: found v1.52 
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.22)     ok: found v0.33 

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v1.45)     not found 
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.00)     ok: found v4.012 
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found 

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.39 
Checking for                Chart (v2.1)      ok: found v2.4.1 
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       ok: found v1.56 
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       ok: found v0.86 
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       ok: found v1.44 
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       ok: found v3.32 
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    ok: found v5.502 
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v5.834 
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.4)    ok: found v0.9.6 
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       ok: found v0.43 
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.15 
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       ok: found v0.20 
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v0.714 
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       ok: found v0.96 
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      ok: found v2.32 
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       ok: found v1.04 
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.40)     ok: found v3.64 
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       ok: found v0.09 
Checking for Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper (any)       ok: found v1.316 
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       ok: found v1.202 
Checking for          TheSchwartz (any)       ok: found v1.10 
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       ok: found v0.81 
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) ok: found v2.000004 
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.93)     ok: found v0.95 
Checking for   Math-Random-Secure (v0.05)     ok: found v0.06 
WARNING: We could not check the configuration of Apache. This sometimes
happens when you are not running checksetup.pl as root. To see the
problem we ran into, run: /usr/sbin/apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

the module is Installed

```
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.15
```

However, in the Parameters->Email - I do not see SMTP:TLS available.

I have installed also the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl
sudo apt-get install libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```

as well as:

```
CPAN: install Net::SMTP::TLS
```

I don't think any code changes needed in order for this to work, but who knows.

According to Q/A  https://serverfault.com/questions/83113/bugzilla-mail-delivery-method-using-tls-for-gmail
I added the line

```
use Email::Send::SMTP::TLS;
```

to Mailer.pm file.
That caused a problem

Software error:

```
> Can't locate Email/Send/SMTP/TLS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .
> lib/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi lib /etc/perl
> /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5
> /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10
> /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 48. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 48. Compilation
> failed in require at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 35. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 35. Compilation
> failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 40. BEGIN failed--compilation
> aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 40. Compilation failed in require at
> /var/www/bugzilla/editparams.cgi line 28. BEGIN failed--compilation
> aborted at /var/www/bugzilla/editparams.cgi line 28. For help, please
> send mail to the webmaster (webmaster@localhost), giving this error
> message and the time and date of the error.
```

Please advise.

*to note that yesterday I had a feeling that I don't have Bugzilla 4.0 installed :-)  anyway, I checked, and it is 4.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to setting up SMTP on your own server, you can even use Gmail as the preferred SMTP server.

I had an installation of Bugzilla 4.0.2 on a Ubuntu9.10 server running Apache2.2/Perl5.10 and I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://rndm-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/05/bugzilla-issue-tracking-send-mail.html)